# Phonegap support Indexeddb

Tags: cordova, indexeddb

**1 -** Can I use in Phonegap "*Indexeddb*" Database? 
(regarding the phonegap documentation, phonegap supports only "localstorag" and "SQLite")

**2 -** what does the browser support means?(for an example if "safari" doesn't supports indexeddb, that means the ios doesn't support indexeddb in Phonegap?)

I would be very happy, if you could explain this questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 - This articles might help you - https://bitbucket.org/axemclion/indexeddb-cordova-ios/overview and http://blog.nparashuram.com/2012/10/indexeddb-example-on-cordova-phonegap_12.html

For question 2- Except Safari, every modern browsers(IE 10+, Chrome, Mozilla) now have a support for IndexedDB.

Comment: I see that phonegap now supports indexeddb on all the phones exception wp7,wp8 and symbian on its [website](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support) So the answer to the 2nd question is still unclear for me because I want to know if phonegap on iOS supports indexeddb or not?

Answer (score 1):

> **IndexedDB**
>
> This API is available in the underlying WebView. Indexed DB offers
>   more features than LocalStorage but fewer than WebSQL.
>
> The following platforms support IndexedDB:
>
> Windows Phone 8, BlackBerry 10

As seen [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)

But a more updated platform support can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb)

Answer (score 1):

Following browsers now/will support indexedDB soon. So they should work with/without cordova

- Windows Phone 8 - Incomplete/Missing some sub features
- BlackBerry 10 - Older version of spec is supported
- Android 4.4 - Supported
- iOS 8 - Supported but buggy

All desktop browser except IE support latest IndexedDB spec. IE 10/ 11  support the latest spec but are missing a few features(http://goo.gl/VoGuWQ)

Answer (score 0):

For my work we've created a business application which stores its information in IndexedDb and WebSQL for iOS. It has really been a struggle to get the databases to work on all different platforms. We currently support iOS 6+, Android 2.3+ and Windows 8(.1). We've managed to get it to work using the [IndexedDb Polyfill](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim) which is an abstraction layer over WebSQL, which enables you to have the same interface for both IndexedDb and WebSQL.

Note that some browsers have poor IndexedDb support, especially early Android versions. If you have any questions on the polyfill feel free to ask.